# unable to add member to channel in twilio ip messaging

Tags: php, rest, twilio-php

i created a channel using rest api in twilio,next i am trying to add member to it but i was failed.here is my code

```
require('Services/Twilio.php');

// Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACCOUNT_SID";
$token = "AUTH_TOKEN";

// Initialize the client
$client = new IPMessaging_Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Retrieve the service
$service = $client->services->get("SERVICE_SID");

// Retrieve the channel
$channel = $service->channels->get("CHANNEL_ID");

// Add the member
$member = $channel->members.create(array(
    "identity" => "JOHN",
));
print $member;
```

ERROR i am getting :

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function create() in 
>   **twilio/sendsms.php** on line **101**

if i changed it to

```
$member = $channel->members->create(array(
    "identity" => "JOHN",
));
```

> ERROR : Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with
>   message 'Missing required parameter Identity in the post body' in
>   twilio/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php:297

Kindly update me on this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You should use key 'Identity' with first capital letter on

> $member = $channel->members->create(array(
>       "identity" => "JOHN", ));